# cannot load such file -- mimemagic/overlay (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

Maybe it removed in new version, so how to set 'mimemagic' with old version?, please!

```
/home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- mimemagic/overlay (LoadError)
    from /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in `register'
    from /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require'
    from /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
    from /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require' ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believed this is related to the recent changes in mimemagic.
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/41757

After i upgraded the rails to 6.1.3.1, I had the same issues and solved it by changing mimemagic version to 0.3.8 in Gemfile.lock file.